# Where is the <code> style in LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

LibreOffice doesn't seem to have an equivalent to the HTML `<code>` style for paragraphs. (They have Preformatted text but that's for characters, not paragraphs.)

I am using the Styles and Formatting dialog in LibreOffice 5.3.2.2. I have tried selecting both HTML styles and All styles options.

(The purpose of this exercise is to create a new .docx template for Pandoc; I am using Pandoc to generate a .docx file from Markdown input.)

Or am I wrong? Is there a way to access a  `<code>` style in LibreOffice Writer documents?

Answer (score 2):

At least with current version, when showing the <kbd>F11</kbd> "Styles" side-bar there is a predefined style `Preformatted Text` that can be used as code style.

For inline text, a "Character Style" `Source text` is predefined. Switching between character and paragraph styles is done by clicking buttons at the top of the "Styles" side-bar.

If superuser.com-like highlighted source-code is wanted, there is no way around customizing the styles currently. An effect similar to

```
this
```

can be obtained by setting a background color and borders for the `Preformatted text` style, or by creating a child style that adds those.

[image]

[image]

*Edit.* There doesn't seem to be any way to emulate rounded corners, which in HTML are easily obtained with with `border-radius` CSS attribute. They can be emulated by putting rectangles with rounded corners behind objects, but it is not an option for text boxes, frames, paragraphs, character styles directly.

As far as I can tell, the same applies in MS Office, and both for text documents (Writer, Word) and presentations (Impress, PowerPoint).